# How do we map the logical table to the tablespace?

Tags: postgresql, tablespace

How do we map the logical table to the tablespace?

Does Postgres automatically creates tablespaces when we create a table or a schema?

Answer (score 0):

Tablespaces and schemas are independent from each other: the first concerns the physical placement of the table, the second the namespace.

PostgreSQL automatically creates a tablespace: it is called `pg_default` and is located in the `base` subdirectory of the data directory.

All tables you create are placed there unless:

- You use the `TABLESPACE` clause of `CREATE TABLE` to place it elsewhere.
- The table is in a database with a different tablespace.
- You set the `default_tablespace` parameter to a different tablespace.

Tablespaces are rarely needed, and usually it is best to keep all tables in the default tablespace.